# Loop to display numbers between 2 registers in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to create a loop to display numbers between the values of 2 registers which are inputted by the user at an earlier stage in the program.

So for an example:

- `$s0` = 5
- `$s1` = 1

then the output would be: 5 4 3 2 1

My logic is:

```
move $t1,$s0
loop:
move $t1, $s1
# branch to loop if
# greater than or equal to zero.

bgez $t1, loop
```

but this is wrong as I think it's just stuck in a continuos loop and doesn't print the values.

Comment: Before you can perform your branch, you have to actually make the comparison. A move alone is not enough. (and you have to actually print the value)

Comment: @JeffMercado How do you suggest doing this?

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like:

```
void printnumbetween(int low, int high)
{
  while(high >= low)
  {
    printf("%d ",high);
    high--;
  }
  return;
}
```

In assembly language, you could do:

```
printnumbetween:
                        #assume $a0 is "int low", $a1 is "int high"
  addiu $sp, -12        #to store variables during printf-call
  sw $ra, 12($sp)       #save return address
  sw $s0, 8($sp)        #free up caller-saved register
  sw $s1, 4($sp)        #ditto
  addu $s0, $zero, $a0  #move arguments to caller-saved registers
  addu $s1, $zero, $a1
  bgt $s0, $s1, endfun  #if (low > high) return

loop:
  addu $a0, $zero, $s1  #move high to argument register
  ...                   #set up other arguments for printf()
  jal printf            #call printf()
  addiu $s1, $s1, -1    #high--
  ble $s0, $s1, loop    #if-converted loop: if (low <= high) goto loop

endfun:
  lw $ra, 12($sp)
  lw $s0, 8($sp)         #restore caller-saved registers
  lw $s1, 4($sp)
  addiu $sp, 12          #restore stack
  jal $ra
```

The exact semantics of saving stuff on the stack may vary (does the stack-pointer point to the first *empty* address, or the last *used* address?), as do the requirements to calling `printf()`, which is varargs and thus ugly.

Comment: Yeah I understand loops very well in java but when it comes to MIPS assembly language I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: @JohnnyC: Have a look at my edit. I strongly advise learning a bit of C if you want to work with assembly. Also, don't just post a few lines of assembly. Think in whole functions, otherwise you're missing context.